# What is the use of transport in VHDL?

Tags: compilation, vhdl

I have seen an example written in a VHDL file

Example snippet,

```
architecture  aaa of bbb is
signal   ccc : std_logic

begin

ccc <= transport global_en_lb;

....
```

I just want to know about transport in the above snippet.
What does it means?

Comment: TL/DR : Transport delays model transmission lines.

Comment: For the given example transport delay and inertial delay behave exactly the same due to the inertial rejection limit being 0 when no **after** *time_expression* is given in the waveform element and no inertial rejection limit being explicitly supplied in the delay mechanism. See IEEE Std 1076-2008, 10.5.2 Simple signal assignments (10.5.2.1, starting at para 5, look for first use of **transport**).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transport delays are idealised: they model propagation through a device or connection with infinite frequency response. Any input pulse, no matter how short, produces an output pulse. You could model an ideal transmission line with a transport delay, for example - any and all input changes propagate through the line. Transport delays can also be useful in testbenches for queuing up transactions on a driver.

Inertial delays approximate real-world delays. They're more complex but, in short, if you try to propagate a pulse where the pulse width is less than the propagation delay through the device or wire, then the pulse disappears. Inertial delays are the default in VHDL if you can't see a `transport` or `inertial` keyword.

At the HDL level, the actual difference between the two is in what happens when you schedule a new transaction for a signal when that signal already has scheduled transactions. For transport delays the transactions are just queued up; for inertial transactions the simulator may merge them.

On your Verilog comment: this was a bit of an after-though in Verilog (like so much else). However, a delay on the RHS of a non-blocking assignment models a transport delay:

```
always @(x)
   y <= #10 ~x;   // transport
```

Continuous assignments don't queue transactions, so model inertial delays:

```
assign #10 y = ~x;  // inertial
```

Answer (score 0):

In VHDL "`transport`" keyword is used to model delays for simulations.

The transport delay model just delays the change in the output by the time specified in the `after` clause.

The transport delay, which is used to model the delay introduced by wiring. With transport delay any pulse of small width is propagated to the output. The transport delay is especially useful for modeling delay line drivers, wire delays on PC board, and on path delays on ASIC.

To understand in terms how exactly it behaves with simulation refer [link](http://vhdl.renerta.com/mobile/source/vhd00023.htm)

Comment: Is this the same # delay in verilog?

Comment: Its not the exact same but in simple terms transport delays are wire delays. To model transport delays in verilog, iniside always block the delay should be placed at the rhs side eg: a<= #1 b;

Comment: Would you pleaselet me know what kind of different exactly for example? It will be very useful..

Comment: #delay in verilog is similar to 'wait for' in VHDL, For example if you want to wait for  a 5 ns then 'wait for 5 ns' construct can be used in VHDL, moreover when wait for used inside a process it can be used as an infinite series with specific interval mentioned in the wait for.

Comment: You have been already answered before like this what I want "Its not the exact same but in simple terms transport delays are wire delays. To model transport delays in verilog, iniside always block the delay should be placed at the rhs side eg: a<= #1 b; –  Emman Jul 15 at 9:19"  Thanks!